# Django TypeError when accessing a link by get_absolute_url()

Tags: python, django

Good day.

So i'm going through **Django 2 by Example** and i've encoutered a strange error when visiting a object from list of objects.

> TypeError at /1/black-tea/
>
> product_detail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

The type it recieves is correct so small help would be appriciated.

code from `views.py`

```
def product_detail(request, product_id, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug,
                                id=product_id, available=True)
    return render(request, 'shop/product/detail.html',
                  {'product': product})
```

`models.py`

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,
                                 related_name='products',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d',
                              blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('shop:product_detail',
                       args=[self.id, self.slug])
```

`urls.py`

```
path('<int:id>/<slug:slug>/', product_detail, name='product_detail'),
```

**Code from template**

```
<div id="main" class="product-list">
        <h1>{% if category %} {{ category.name }}{% else %}Products{% endif %}</h1>
        {% for product in products %}
            <div class="item">
                <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">
                    <img src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}
                    {% else %}{% static 'img/images.jpeg' %}{% endif %}">
                </a>
                <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">{{ product.name }}</a>
                <br>
                ${{ product.price }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Comment: in urls.py change it to `path('<int:product_id>/<slug:slug>/', product_detail, name='product_detail'),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`product_detail` arguments should match your url mapping parameters in `urls.py`. The function definition should has arguments `id`, `slug`:

```
def product_detail(request, id, slug):
    ...
```

Comment: Just for a note, it's a bad practice to use `id` as a named argument because it can conflict with the built-in id object